# Show total file size while transferring files?

Tags: nautilus, files, filesystem

I'm fairly new to the Linux world.
One thing that keeps nudging me is that the transfer progress bar doesn't show total size of the data being transferred. (It only shows number of files transferred out of the remaining ones.)
What can be done to make both the information available (size & number of files) to the user while transferring data.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are you using standard Ubuntu or a flavor? Release? What shows and what doesn't depend on the file management software and that may depend on the desktop environment.

Comment: I'm using standard Ubuntu. And file management is Nautilus. Does that help? @GabrielaGarcia

Comment: Yes, it does but unfortunately the new Nautilus versions have been progressively stripped down of features. You can install other that does what you want, for example Nemo (the default one in the Cinnamon DE), but it's recommended to keep the default. In other words, you can have as many different programs as you want for the same purpose but it's recommended to keep the defaults as they are. You'll find many tutorials with instructions on how to make the alternative one default but IMO it's not a good idea.